# Wrong date being parsed

Tags: plugin, rss

I am using ajw feedparser to output a feed from Songkick. It has been working correctly up until recently but now the date is showing as a day earlier than it should eg. 15th April instead of 16th.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated! (The feedparser plugin support forum is pretty dead!)

```
{exp:ajw_feedparser 
url="http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/304376/calendar.xml?apikey=2bpAQkQkQ3wYFukP" 
itempath="/resultsPage/results/event"
         cache_refresh="60"
         limit="3"}
    <h5>{start@date format='%M %j %Y'} &nbsp; <a href="{@uri}">
{if series@displayName}{series@displayName}, {/if}
{if venue@displayName}{venue@displayName}{/if}</a></h5> 
      {/exp:ajw_feedparser}
```

Comment: It just uses regular EE date formatting so it shouldn't be the plugin which is causing the issue. Are you sure this tag is correct? `{start@date format='%M %j %Y'}`? And have you checked the dates in the feed itself are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A weird thing has happened and the date has resolved itself again without any changes on my part.
Makes me think it was a songkick issue that has now been resolved!